# Facebook Like Button error

Tags: facebook, facebook-like

The facebook 'like' button isn't working on my webpage when i upload it to the web. It works perfectly on my computer though. Any guesses as to why this is happening ?

http://savetheearth.99k.org/pledge.htm is the URL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think the problem is in the url you have provided. As i check in your page source the i frame has following code :

`<iframe src="http://www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?href=earthsave.tk&amp;layout=standard&amp;show_faces=false&amp;width=450&amp;action=like&amp;font=verdana&amp;colorscheme=light&amp;height=35" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" style="border:none; overflow:hidden; width:450px; height:35px;" allowTransparency="true"></iframe>`

Where it should have been:

`<iframe src="http://www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?href=http%3A%2F%2Fsavetheearth.99k.org%2Fpledge.htm&amp;layout=standard&amp;show_faces=false&amp;width=450&amp;action=like&amp;font=verdana&amp;colorscheme=light&amp;height=35" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" style="border:none; overflow:hidden; width:450px; height:35px;" allowTransparency="true"></iframe>`

the problem was in your url:

`src="http://www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?href=earthsave.tk`

Comment: @Voila Wshewwwwww!!! after so much diving in your html i got it!!!! it simple problem you have got an extran </iframe> closing tag. just after the original closing tag for the like plugin iframe you have one more extra iframe closing that is preventing the like   button from working. Correct and i am sure your page will work,. i tried it myself after hosting your page in my web server.                                                                       .A good website though!. keep it up.

Answer (score 0):

The like button shows up for me just fine - I'm not even logged into facebook.

Answer (score 0):

Two reasons we have found for this:

**Simple Redirect:**
If your site page has a redirect on it you will get an error.

**www prefix redirect:**
Facebook always tries to access your domain without the www prefix. If you have an auto redirect to send users from "example.com" to "www.example.com" - even if you pass the url to facebook as "www.example.com", the crawler tries to access the url without the www which results in an error.

Comment: any integration with FB tends to be a bit of a minefield in our experience